Invertibility Radon transform for functions with compact support
I have seen formulas for the inverse of the Radon transform for functions belonging to the Schwarz space. Im wondering if these formulas holds for Sobolev functions with compact support.
The Radon transform for a real valued function $f(x)$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is defined as
\begin{align}
\mathcal{R}[f](\omega,p)=\int_{\omega \cdot x=p}f(x) dm(x)
\end{align}
where $\omega\in S^{n-1}$, $p\in \mathbb{R}$ and $dm(x)$ is the Euclidean measure on the hyperplane $\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n: \omega \cdot x =p\}$. Hence, $\mathcal{R}[f](\omega,p)$ is a real valued function defined on $S^{n-1}\times \mathbb{R}$.
Given a real valued function $\varphi(\omega, p)$ defined on $S^{n-1}\times \mathbb{R}$
one defines the dual tranform as
\begin{align}
\mathcal{R}^*[\varphi](x)=c\int_{S^{n-1}} \varphi(\omega,\omega\cdot x) d\omega
\end{align}
where $c$ is a normalization constant and $d\omega$ is the surface measure of $S^{n-1}$. Thus, $\mathcal{R}^*[\varphi]$ is a real valued function defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$.
I have looked at the inversions formulas in Helgason's book where he first defines another operator $\Lambda$. Given $\varphi\in \mathcal{S}(S^{n-1}\times \mathbb{R})$ (a smooth rapidly decreasing function), he defines (page 19)
\begin{align}
\Lambda [\varphi](b,c)=\begin{cases}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dp^{n-1}}\varphi(\omega,p), \quad n \text{ odd}\\
\mathcal{H}_p\frac{d^{n-1}}{dp^{n-1}}\varphi(\omega,p), \quad n \text{ even}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
where $\mathcal{H}_p$ is the Hilbert transform w.r.t $p$, see wikipedia.
Then, in Theorem 3.6 (page 19) he states the inversion formula:
Given $f\in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ one has
\begin{align}
c_nf(x)=\mathcal{R}^*[\Lambda\mathcal{R}[f]]
\end{align}
for a dimension dependent constant $c_n$. Hence, this formula, as stated above, is valid for $f\in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.
Later in his book (page 28) he writes: "As a result of this proposition the smoothness assumption can be dropped in the inversion formula. In particular, we can state the following result."
And he states the following result (Corollary 5.9):
If the dimension $n$ is odd and if $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and has compact support, then
\begin{align}
cf=L^{(n-1)/2}\mathcal{R}^*\big[\mathcal{R}[f]\big]
\end{align}
where $L$ is the Laplacian on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and the derivatives are interpreted in the distributional sense.
My question is:
If $f\in H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for some $s\in \mathbb{N}$ and $f$ has compact support, is the  formula in Theorem 3.6 valid?
Clearly if $f\in H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and has compact support, the assumptions of Corollary 5.9 is fulfilled.
But Corollary 5.9 is only stated for odd $n$ and we have the Laplacian instead of $\Lambda$. I would like an inversion formula in terms of the operators $\mathcal{R}^*, \frac{d^{n-1}}{dp^{n-1}}, \mathcal{H}_p, \mathcal{R}$ valid for odd and even dimensions, like the one in Theorem 3.6.
Any suggestions on references or solutions are highly appriciated.
